# CrytoJS AES: Encrypted string gets decrypted to empty string

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I was tinkering with crypto-js and AES.

I have a seemingly straightforward piece of code which takes a plainText and encrypts it using AES with a key and an initial vector.

When I try to decrypt the encrypted text, it gets decrypted to empty string for some reason.

This is the snippet:

```
const { enc, AES } = require("crypto-js");

const KEY = enc.Utf8.parse("this is a key");
const IV = enc.Utf8.parse("this is initial vector");

const originalText = "someone@example.com";

const hash = AES.encrypt(originalText, KEY, { iv: IV });
const hashText = hash.toString();

console.log(`"${originalText}" was encrypted to "${hashText}"`);

const hashTextCopy = `${hashText}`;
const decrypt = AES.decrypt(hashTextCopy, KEY, { iv: IV });
const decryptText = decrypt.toString(enc.Utf8);

console.log(`"${hashTextCopy}" was decrypted to "${decryptText}"`);
```

The output I get is:

```
"someone@example.com" was encrypted to "IgyDXGNVD8IokknoZqjamG0QecGvBM/dyxx4il8gCHA="
"IgyDXGNVD8IokknoZqjamG0QecGvBM/dyxx4il8gCHA=" was decrypted to ""
```

Can someone explain what is going on? I have seen quite a few examples of it over the Internet and they all seem to working just fine. But here, the text is not getting decrypted.

**PS**: The version I am using is `"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try changing your code ever so slightly, this works for me.

As stated in the comments, I believe the problem with your initial example was the key length.

```
const { enc, AES } = require("crypto-js");

// Keep as a string..
const KEY = "this is a key";
const IV = enc.Utf8.parse("this is initial vector");

const originalText = "someone@example.com";

const hash = AES.encrypt(originalText, KEY, { iv: IV });
const hashText = hash.toString();

console.log(`"${originalText}" was encrypted to "${hashText}"`);

const hashTextCopy = `${hashText}`;
const decrypt = AES.decrypt(hashTextCopy, KEY, { iv: IV });
const decryptText = decrypt.toString(enc.Utf8);

console.log(`"${hashTextCopy}" was decrypted to "${decryptText}"`);
```

This also works:

```
const { enc, AES } = require("crypto-js");

// 128-bit key works nicely
const KEY = enc.Hex.parse("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
const IV = enc.Utf8.parse("this is initial vector");

const originalText = "someone@example.com";

const hash = AES.encrypt(originalText, KEY, { iv: IV });
const hashText = hash.toString();

console.log(`"${originalText}" was encrypted to "${hashText}"`);

const hashTextCopy = `${hashText}`;
const decrypt = AES.decrypt(hashTextCopy, KEY, { iv: IV });
const decryptText = decrypt.toString(enc.Utf8);

console.log(`"${hashTextCopy}" was decrypted to "${decryptText}"`);
```

The key:

```
const KEY = enc.Utf8.parse("abcdfghi");
```

Will also work correctly (since it's 128-bits). 256 would work too.

```
const KEY = enc.Utf8.parse("abcdfghijklmnopq");
```

If you just use a pass phrase, a 256-bit key will be generated from it.

Comment: Strange, that seems to work. It would be good if you can explain the behaviour

Comment: I believe the encryption behaves differently when you use a CryptoJS.WordArray as your key input (as you were doing initially). It may expect the key to conform to the fixed lengths required by AES-128, AES-256 etc.

Comment: I believe key length is the issue when you use a CryptoJS.WordArray. I'll update the answer. You'll notice it works in the second example if we use a 128-bit key, but not if we change this length. If we do, the response is "" (not a particularly nice failure mode :( )

Comment: Key length seems to be the issue yes, It seems that the when using `enc.xxx.parse(key)`, the length of `key` must be a multiple of 8

Comment: Thanks for the help +1. I will accept the answer if you can link to a source/documentation that mentions the criteria on the key.

Comment: I think the best we can do is here: https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/.  "CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the variant by the size of the key you pass in. If you use a passphrase, then it will generate a 256-bit key." I actually believe it should throw an error if the key length passed is incorrect. This explains why a plain passphrase will always work, since it generates a 256-bit key from it.